# Redirect based on incoming domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

This might be strange situation, feel free to ask for any clearing up if i don't explain the situation clear enough.

Currently we have a corporate website called www.corporate.com (Wordpress website)

We also have our previous website from the corporation we fused with www.fusedcorporate.com

At the moment when you go to any page on www.fusedcorporate.com you get directed to www.corporate.com

Is there any way in wordpress to check incoming requests if the come from "fusedcorporate.com" and when they do to request to www.corporate.com/fused ?

Another option i'm thinking of is to settle it on a DNS level, but i don't know how to makes calls to a domain redirect to a certain page on a different website.

Comment: Not sure about wordpress, but this is a general php question :)

Most browsers will provide the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] which provides the incoming domain, some logic can quickly solve the redirect with header location.

Comment: @Patrick This is a more of a general .htaccess question rather than PHP.

Comment: Can you clarify the URLs you are redirecting from/to. Are you literally redirecting from _any_ URL to a single URL (the document root, or `/fused` subdirectory) on the new site (as your question implies), or from _any_ URL to the corresponding URL on the new site. eg `fusedcorporate.com/<anything>` to `corporate.com/fused/<anything>`?

Comment: Well id solve it with php and not htaccess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a .htaccess file and add the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fusedcorporate.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fusedcorporate.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.corporate.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. The suggestion you made solved my problem. thank you